# how can I calculate mean of every 6 rows in a data frame based on the condition of other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a dataframe in R, contain 3000 rows and  2 columns (temp, flag), I am trying to calculate "meantemp" as the third column for every 6 rows if the corresponding values in flag column are not NA, SO if flage values are equal to NA I want to show in the meantemp column NA value. sorry for this question.

Comment: Please provide an example data along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = ceiling(row_number()/6)) %>%
  mutate(meantemp = if(all(is.na(flag))) mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE) else NA) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group) -> df
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but it doesn't work. Actually I already calculated the third column for mean temp.. No I just want to create fourth column using flag and meantemp and I want to say in new column keep the meantemp if corresponding value is not NA and turn the meantemp to Na if corresponding flag is NA

Comment: @Faranakomidi can you provide an example data along with expected output so that it is clear what you are asking for? Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: thank you I find a way to solve it :                                                                                                    hourlyHOBO<-FLAG%>% filter(minute(date_time) %% 10 == 0) %>%
   mutate(meantemp = rollmean(temp, 6, fill = FALSE, align = "right"))%>%
   filter(minute(date_time) == 0)


 hourlyHOBO$HOBOmean <- ifelse( is.na(hourlyHOBO$flag1), NA, hourlyHOBO$meantemp)